# how to make dropdown with input field in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

i am making dropdown list with input field in angular.js but got no success

the code which i using..

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
            <h2>filter input</h2>
            <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test | orderBy : 'name'">
                    {{ x.name + ',' + x.country }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName= "";
        $scope.lastName= "";
    });
</script>
<script src="namescontrol.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by dropdown list with input field? You are showing list items in your code ,not dropdown list.Can u share a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: i want that, when i type any letter in input field then the dropdown list will be appear of related letter, i mean list should appear with filteration

Comment: Okay. can u share a plunker or fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Check the working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cLzqkej/).

Use a customized filter to perform the filtering. Since `ng-model` binds to the value `key`. Whenever key is changed, the `items` will be filtered and the view will be changed.

```
angular.module('Joy',[])
.controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
    $scope.key = '';
    $scope.search = function (value) {
        return value.indexOf($scope.key) >= 0;
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="key">
    <div>
        <li ng-repeat="item in (items | filter:search)" ng-bind="item"></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Update 1

If you want to hide the list initially: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cLzqkej/1/):

```
$scope.search = function (value) {
    return $scope.key !== '' && value.indexOf($scope.key) >= 0;
};
```

---

#### Update 2

I have developed an open source project [`angular-sui`](https://github.com/agongdai/angular-sui) based on Angular and [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com). There is a directive `sui-select`, which is exactly what you want. Please check the [Demo](http://agongdai.github.io/angular-sui/docs/#/api/sui.select.directive:suiSelect).

Comment: dropdown list is there already. i want that dropdown list not show before type anything

Comment: Thank u  for giving answer, joy

Comment: @TanveerAhmad My pleasure. Please kindly upvote/accept :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is autocomplete functionality. AngularUI offers this through their Typeahead directive. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

You want to have something like this:

`<input type="text" ng-model="test"  typeahead="name for name in names"/>`

The directive will dynamically generate the list so you don't need to create that explicitly yourself.

Comment: Heres a plunker to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/aUfWBBgxpGjUN6u9eGsN?p=preview